# TIMESTAMP and Standard SQL in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying (and failing) to perform the following query in BigQuery using Standard SQL

```
SELECT
  user_id
FROM
  dataset.table
WHERE
  timestamp > TIMESTAMP("2017-09-18 00:00")
```

I constantly get the message

```
Query Failed
Error: Invalid timestamp: '2017-09-18 00:00'
```

I tried, desperate, with `2017-09-18T00:00` or like the Legacy SQL `timestamp > "2017-09-18 00:00"` without success.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What type is your `timestamp` column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe a valid timestamp has a time portion with hours, minutes, *and* seconds.  Your timestamp literal omits the seconds portion.  Try including it:

```
SELECT
    user_id
FROM
    dataset.table
WHERE
    timestamp > TIMESTAMP('2017-09-18 00:00:00')
```

The reason you need to include seconds in the timestamp, and why your current timestamp makes no sense, is that BigQuery internally stores timestamps as epoch seconds.  Without specifying seconds, your timestamp cannot reliably be stored.

From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types):

> You can describe TIMESTAMP data types as either UNIX timestamps or calendar datetimes. BigQuery stores TIMESTAMP data internally as a UNIX timestamp with microsecond precision.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: What is the difference between TIMESTAMP('2017-09-18 00:00:00') and CAST('2017-09-18 00:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP)?

Comment: @PalakJain I just glossed the docs for both, and they both support string to timestamp conversion, with optional time zone.  They are synonymous from what I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

As the [documentation of bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types) suggests

> Date and time strings
>
> A date and time string in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. The UTC and
>   Z specifiers are supported.

You have provided `2017-09-18 00:00` which is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM` .
You will need to provide `2017-09-18 00:00:00`.

So your query should look as follows

```
SELECT
  user_id
FROM
  dataset.table
WHERE
  timestamp > TIMESTAMP("2017-09-18 00:00:00")
```

Comment: Damn, that's it. Thanks and sorry for the silly question.

Comment: Do you mind giving an example taking time zone into account. For some reasons, this doesn't seem to work: TIMESTAMP("2017-01-09 00:30:00.000 UTC"), the timestamp given will be starting from 06:30:00 indicated "UTC" in that string has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to write this expression without specifying the extra zeros is:

```
TIMESTAMP(DATE "2017-09-18")
```